# function which returns the number of his invocations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new here so I'm sorry if my question is not very clear. I need to write a function in JavaScript which one, after his invocation returns the number of invocations.

Comment: You'll get a much better response if you post some code and demonstrate that you've made some effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should start by reading what's on topic for questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: `var counter = 0; function foo() { return ++counter; }`

Comment: Thanks, I read it and will stop with this stupid questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
var count = 0;

function counter() {
    count++;
    return count;
}

console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
```

To make that `count` variable inaccessible to anything but that function, you can use Javascript's function scoping mechanism:

```
var counter = (function () {
    var count = 0;

    return function () {
        count++;
        return count;
    };
})();

console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been stuck on this question all night. It was for job interview by the way, maybe i need to improve my knowledge before start working. :)

Comment: If you couldn't solve this problem yourself... uhm... yeah... maybe not yet time to work professionally. :)